# For a PDE $u' + Au = f$, if $f$ and $u'$ are smooth does it mean $Au$ is also smooth?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Suppose I have a solution $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$ with $u' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$ of the PDE
$$u' + Au = f$$
where $A:L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)) \to L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$ is an elliptic operator and $f \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$.

If, for some reason, I knew that $u'$ lies in the stronger space $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$, is it valid to say that since
$$Au = f-u' \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega)),$$
that $Au \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$?

I can't see anything wrong with this reasoning but it appears wrong that we have $Au$ in a stronger space, since the operator $A$ is given a priori...

Comment: Do you need estimates for $u$ or for $Au$? For $t>0$, $Au$ is as smooth as $f$, but as $t\to 0^+$ things might get unpleasant.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I have everything I know about $u$, I just want to know that $Au$ has the stated property. I don't really understand why $Au$ is bad when $t \to 0$, but I won't be taking such a limit anyway.

Comment: It is definitely true that $Au\in L^2\big([0,T]; L^2(\Omega)\big)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you know that $f$ and $u'$ belong to $L^2\big([0,T]; L^2(\Omega)\big)$, and $Au = f-u'$, then $ Au\in L^2\big([0,T]; L^2(\Omega)\big)$. After all, $ L^2\big([0,T]; L^2(\Omega)\big) $ is a linear space. If you are unsure because the ODE   holds in some weak sense (e.g., as distributions), consider that the difference of two distributions that are identified with $L^2$ functions is itself naturally identified with an $L^2$ function.